# Swap In Insertion Sort Not Working In a Doubly Link List

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

This insertion sort belongs to a doubly linked list. It doesn't seem print anything out. Sorry if this is messy. I am fairly new to posting things. I have debugged it by putting in sysout. I believe there is a problem with the swapping I used sysout & I noticed that this is where the problem was occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have also checked my app class which seems fine.

```
public boolean insertionSort()
{
 if (getFirst().next != null)
{
   return false;
}
  Link current = getFirst().next;
  Link current2 = current;

  while(current != null){
   current2 = current;
  while(current2.prev != null){
      int tempID = Integer.valueOf(current2.Data.getID());
      int temp2ID = Integer.valueOf(current2.prev.Data.getID());
if(tempID < temp2ID )
  {
    swap(current2, current.prev);
  }  
    current2 = current2.prev;
 }
    current = current.next;
 }
    return true;
}


 public void swap(Link x, Link y)
  {      

   Link previousNode1 = x.prev;

   Link nextNode1 = x.next;

   Link previousNode2 = y.prev;

   Link nextNode2 = y.next;


   if (x.next == y || y.next == x)
   {

       previousNode1.next = y;

       y.prev = (previousNode1);

       nextNode2.next = (x);

       x.next = (nextNode2);

       x.prev = (y);

       y.next = (x);
   }


   else
   {
       y.prev = (previousNode1);

       y.next = (nextNode1);

       nextNode1.prev = (y);

       previousNode1.next = (y);

       x.prev = (previousNode2);

       x.next = (nextNode2);

       nextNode2.prev = (x);

       previousNode2.next = (x);
   }

 } // end swap
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only given a portion of your code. So it is difficult to figure out what exactly is wrong. But at a first glance to your insertionSort method, this is what is wrong: At the very beginning you have a condition statement

```
if (getFirst().next != null){
   return false;
}
```

This means that the function will return immediately if getFirst().next is **not null**. If the program flow satisfies this condition i.e. getFirst().next is null, you assign this **null** to two variables current and current2. And then you run a while loop with the condition `while(current != null){...}`. How is this function supposed to do anything?

First, correct the if condition. Probably you need to return only if getFirst().next is null (not return if it is not null). Then, see if you get your desired output or not. If not, please give more detail about your problem.